# Finding type of the class which is calling a method in Java

Tags: java, oop, class

I'd like to know what's the type of the object which is calling a method in another class in Java, e.g. :

```
 class A{
   public A(){
     //..
   }
   public void method1{
      //here I'd like to find what's the type of the object which is calling this method 
   }
  }

  class B{
    public B(){
      A a = new A();
      a.method1();
     }
   }

  class C{
     public C(){
        A a = new A();
        a.method1();
     }
   }
```

Comment: the only thing that comes to my mind is to throw an exception and analyze the stacktrace, but that would be a horrible practice

Comment: It's less horrible if you simply instantiate the exception. You don't need to throw it. But you can interrogate the current thread for its stack instead

Comment: Why do you need to know this? I'm vaguely horrified at what you could possibly be doing that can't be accomplished by passing in some sort of enum flag instead. You're going to create some very brittle, tightly coupled code.

Comment: Enum flag ? Why not pass in the reference to the calling class in the method parameters ?

Comment: So how are going to define it in the method parameters as you don't have prior knowledge about the class of that input parameter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by inspecting the stack upon the method call to your code. Check out [Thread.getStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29) and use the current thread as returned by

```
Thread.currentThread()
```

You can work your way back up the stack trace array and determine the chain of callers. Note the caveat in the documentation however:

> Some virtual machines may, under some circumstances, omit one or more
>   stack frames from the stack trace. In the extreme case, a virtual
>   machine that has no stack trace information concerning this thread is
>   permitted to return a zero-length array from this method.

If you need to find out who called you for a subset of your classes, I would change the classes such that they implement some `Caller`/`Callee` interfaces and implement method signatures thus:

```
public void doSomething(..., Caller caller);
```

where your calling class implements `Caller`. That way you're enforcing some relatively type-safe method calls and parameter passing.

Comment: So what should be done on these machines ?

Comment: that means you can't find out who called your code on those machines

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```